# GWT DatePicker to recognize Calendar Icon click

Tags: gwt, calendar, datepicker, click, handler

I'm using a DatePicker widget, and I put a little calendar image next to it.  When you click on the actual DatePicker textbox, the calendar popup pops up (as it should).  I'm looking to add this click handling to the little calendar image too, so that the user can click either the box or the image to see the calendar popup.  Is there an easy way to do this?

I thought it might be something like this:

```
calendarImage.addClickHandler(datePick.getTextBox().getClickHandler())
```

But it doesn't seem that anything like this exists.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a clickhandler to the image that sets the datepicker visible.

It will become something like this:

```
private DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
private TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
private Image icon = new Image("calendar.png");

public void onModuleLoad() {

    datePicker.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<Date>() {

        @Override
        public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<Date> event) {
            Date date = event.getValue();
            String dateStr = DateTimeFormat.getFormat(DateTimeFormat.PredefinedFormat.DATE_MEDIUM).format(date);
            textBox.setText(dateStr);
            datePicker.setVisible(false);
        }
    });
    datePicker.setVisible(false);

    icon.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
            datePicker.setVisible(true);        
        }
    });

    RootPanel.get().add(icon);
    RootPanel.get().add(textBox);
    RootPanel.get().add(datePicker);
}
```

Comment: Great - thank you!  I used datePicker.showDatePicker() instead of datePicker.getDatePicker().setVisible(true), and it works very well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean `DateBox` when you write `DatePicker`, simply call `showDatePicker` on click of the icon (and/or test `isDatePickerShowing` and call `hideDatePicker`)